# Что такое ngx-bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, angularjs, angular2, angular-cli

Обнаружил, что для подключения bootstrap к Angular рекомендуют исползовать ngx-bootstrap ([How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)).

Но чем это лучше простого скачивания bootstrap (насколько я догадываюсь, так удобнее подключать компоненты bootstrap'овские)? И можете объяснить что это такое -  ngx-bootstrap, откуда оно взялось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простого скачивания недостаточно, так как bootstrap - это набор стилей и *скриптов* с реализацией поведения.

Просто так подключить его в приложение на Angular проблематично, так как не будет связи с инфраструктурой, например, при изменении значения в компоненте, не будет изменяться значение в модели/компоненте/сервисе. Так же могут быть проблемы с правильными временем инициализации компонентов.

`ngx-bootstrap` - это реализация компонентов bootstrap, с помощью Angular. То есть, подключается один модуль, в котором есть все нужные компоненты.